# How to get information about a keysize in php-openssl

Tags: php, mcrypt, php-openssl

I want to change the crypt-functions in my php-app from mcrypt to openssl. Now I'm missing a function like mcrypt_enc_get_key_size() in openssl? How do I can read the max. keysize of a cypher-method in openssl?

Example: blowfish(CFB)

```
mcrypt_enc_get_key_size() returns 56 (Bytes) => 448bit
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function with OpenSSL sadly. One option is to check the key size for each of the supported ciphers and use a switch. If you favor AES, you can do something like this.

```
$method = "AES-256-CBC"; // Or whatever you want

if (preg_match("/^aes-?([0-9]+)/i", $method, $matches)) {
    // AES has the key size in it's name as bits
    $keySize = $matches[1] / 8;

} else {
    $ivSize = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);

    if ($ivSize > 0) {
        /*
         * This will fit will with most.
         * A few might get a larger key than required, but larger is better than smaller
         * since larger keys just get's downsized rather than padded. 
         *
         */
        $keySize = $ivSize * 2;

    } else {
        // Defaults to 128 when IV is not used
        $keySize = 16;
    }
}
```

For example.

BF uses 64bit block size and will in this case get a 128bit keysize. It requires 32bit and takes up to 448bits.

CAST5 uses 64bit block size and requires between 40bit and 128bit key size, in this case it will get 128bit.

It's not perfect, but it will work. Or like mentioned above, you can always check the supported ciphers on http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-cipher-methods.php and manually search for and add max key size for each within a switch or similar.